# Integrating derivative quotient rule

Tags: calculus, integration

(I'm a secondary school student, I'm new to calculus, please don't attack me.)

I've been playing around with integrating various formulas for derivatives, such as the product and quotient rule, and I have found that whilst you can derive the integration by parts formula from the product rule, you can't do the same for the quotient rule, because you will end up with
$$\int\frac{\text{d}u}{v}=\frac{u}{v}+u\int\frac{\text{d}v}{v^2}=\frac{u}{v}+u(-\frac1v)=0,$$ which I'm pretty sure isn't a useful answer.

Comment: You get $\int\frac{du}{v}=\frac{u}{v}+\int \frac{u\,dv}{v^2}$. The $u$ is inside the indefinite integral, not outside. The derivation of this is the same as the integration by parts formula; rather than the usual “$v$” you have “$\frac{1}{v}$”.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

According to the by parts formula,
$\int_{a}^{b}f(x).g(x)dx=[f(x)\int g(x)]_a ^b -\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\int g(x)dx$.
Thus according to your question,
[Here is the actual formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVOUN.png)

So you have done the mistake in the last step.

Comment: Ohh ok I see where I went wrong